# Best way to rewrite urls in css files before production launch?

Tags: css, regex, bash, capistrano, web-deployment

The project i'm currently working on has seen various coders, from various backgrounds. After succesfully writing a clean Capistrano recipe in order minimize css and js files, I'm asking myself how to recognize various url patterns spread around our css codebase, to rewrite them all at once before they go live.
The patterns i'm looking for are

```
url('../../images/
url(../images/
url("../../../images/
url(images/
```

So basically, here's an input example :

```
.test{background:url('/images/test.jpg') no-repeat top left}.pouet{background:url("../../images/bg.png")}
```

Note that in some cases, we have quotes, in others not...
And what i'm trying to obtain

```
.test{background:url('http://www.cdnImages.com/images/test.jpg') no-repeat top left}.pouet{background:url("http://www.cdnImages.com/images/bg.png")}
```

All these must be replaced by my cdn url. The most puzzling thing is how to do so in a way that does not allow any mistakes.

I've come up with a regexp that fits my needs : [rubular permalink](http://rubular.com/r/dpRx9DPjkJ)

I was looking at the sed command, using it as follows

```
sed '/url([^\/](.*?)images/http:\/\/www.cdnImages.com' myFile.css
```

but that doesn't seem to do the job.

My current research lead me to this

```
 find #{current_release}/public/static/css/ -name '*.css' | xargs sed -i 's@url\([^\/](.*?)images|static\/@#{images_cdn}@g'
```

and, while the regular expression perfectly fits the need (check [here to see the catched output](http://rubular.com/r/4fjJ3u3Od6), there seems to be something wrong somewhere.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: better to post before and after examples AND what you have tried so far ;-). Good luck.

Comment: Not much, i've been using sed as follows :  find -type f -name '*.css'| sed -I file -i '' "s|url(\([^)]*\)|url(#{cdn_url}\1|g" file

Comment: mmmm ... also tried  sed '/url\([^\/](.*?)images/cdnUrl.com' myFile.css ... unsuccessfuly

Comment: Sorry, but we're still having to guess about what  you want the final output to look like. Simplified examples that cover all likely cases are sufficient Good luck!

Comment: updated the post with hopefully more details to fit your needs ... sorry

Comment: so please show us the output you get from your 'current research' and  explain why 'something (is) wrong' if it is not obvious. Also if you want to use sed as your solution, you should swap that in as a tag. I don't think many people scan specifically to help solve regex problems, where as I know for sure, people scan for sed problems to solve. Good luck.

Comment: You're using a ruby regex site for sed regex. They're not identical. If you need to also fix links with the word 'static' (per you example on the cached output), please indicate this is part of the problem. Sed can probably do what you need. With some exceptions, you can run 1 copy of sed to make many, many changes to a line. So you would just duplicate the code I've provided and and change images to static (with some possible additional fixes required). Separate the 2 s@..@..@g strings with semicolon. Again, show us the actual minimal output, and show us what is wrong ;-) ! Good luck.

Comment: +1 for @shellter's comment.  Try substituting `perl -pi` for `sed -i`.  I was also going to suggest recasting the regex into `sed`'s regex syntax as an alternative (would need to know which `sed` you have, they differ between themselves, too) but you are using Perl's non-greedy operator which I don't think is supported in any variant of `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with the perfect command, that fits the need :

```
run "find #{current_release}/public/static/css/ -name '*.css' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -E 's@(\.\.\/)+(images|static|img)@#{images_cdn}@g'"
```

works fast and safe !

Answer (score 3):

Here's my test case

```
printf ".test{background:url('/images/test.jpg') no-repeat top left}.pouet{background:url(\"../../images/bg.png\")}\n" \
| sed 's@url[(][^)][^)]*)@url(http://www.cdnImages.com)@g'

.test{background:url(http://www.cdnImages.com) no-repeat top left}.pouet{background:url(http://www.cdnImages.com)}
```

Ah.. one more thing

```
printf ".test{background:url('/images/test.jpg') no-repeat top left}.pouet{background:url(\"../../images/bg.png\")}\n" \
| sed 's@url[(][^)][^)]*)@url('"'"'http://www.cdnImages.com'"'"')@g'

.test{background:url('http://www.cdnImages.com') no-repeat top left}.pouet{background:url('http://www.cdnImages.com')}
```

Note that with some sed's you need to escape the **first** '@' sign like `\@`.

I see your example output keeps the respective `'...'` and `"..."` quote chars that were there. I hope it is OK to change all to `'...'`. If not, that makes the problem more complicated.

As you say this is a production push and '... do so in a way that does not allow any mistakes.', you will need to test the heck of out of this.

To elevate your sed usage, thing about what is happening with search pattern `@url[(][^)][^)]*)@`.

To elevate your shell usage, thing about what/why I changed to `'"'"'http://www.cdnImages.com'"'"'`, in the final round. ;-)

I'm out of time right now.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why people are complicating it, it's pretty simple. I do this kind of thing all the time.

```
data=$(cat <<EOF
.test{background:url('/images/test.jpg') no-repeat top left}.pouet{background:url("../../images/bg.png")}
EOF
)
prefix="http://www.cdnImages.com/"
rule=$(cat <<EOF
s|/*\(\.\./\)*\(images/[^'"]*\)|$prefix\2|g
EOF
)

echo "$data" | sed "$rule"
```

Take note of the escaping of the `\'` and `"$prefix"`.

Comment: As mine is a one liner, I suppose I won't select your answer as the accepted answer. But it does the trick too. thanks.

Comment: The heredoc's are because it is prettier than escaping everything. The one liner would be `echo "$data" | sed 's|/*\(\.\./\)*\(images/[^'\''"]*\)|http://www.cdnImages.com/\2|g'`. A little less pretty.